# How to get the current active view in a region using PRISM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I know that i can get all the registered views in a region with :

```
var vs = mRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegionStatic].Views.ToList();
```

and i can see there is the following code :

```
mRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegionStatic].ActiveViews
```

which is giving a list of Active View, but I'm having my region attached to a ContentControl which always has a single ActiveView. Am i misunderstood or is there a way to get the single active view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`var singleView = regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Great that worked, but how is it that we have a collection for that?

Comment: because [SingleActiveRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.presentation.regions.singleactiveregion.aspx) inherits Region

Comment: Is there a way to get existing VMs using the IoC container (in my case DryIoc)? I tried `this == _Container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>` from the `ShellViewModel` and it evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var singleView = regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault();
```

This is not correct, as it will just bring whatever view that got activated first. not the currently active/visible view.

Can't find a direct solution though, that doesn't involve custom implementation on View or ViewModel.

Comment: Interesting !! , but at the time it was what i needed. can you give more details ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use the `NavigationService` `Journal`. It takes record of all the navigation that takes place in your application. So, you can get the name of the view like this:

```
string name = mRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegionStatic].NavigationService.Journal.CurrentEntry.Uri;
```

Then you can get the view like this:

```
mRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegionStatic].GetView(name);
```

Sweet Right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.Forms & Prism, this works well for me. Change the regionName, change the View Model base to yours.

```
public VisualElement GetCurrentRegionView()
{
    var regionName = "MenuPageRegion";
    var region = RegionManager.Regions[regionName];
    var uri = region.NavigationService.Journal.CurrentEntry.Uri.OriginalString;
    foreach (var view in region.ActiveViews)
    {
        var name = view.GetType().FullName;
        if (name.EndsWith(uri))
            return view;
    }
    return null;
}

public CommonViewModelBase GetCurrentRegionViewModel()
{
    var view = GetCurrentRegionView();
    if (view != null)
    {
        var binding = view.BindingContext;
        if (binding is CommonViewModelBase model)
            return model;
    }
    return null;
}
```